# how to check "ADUser is manager of ADGroup" from powershell comand?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have Active directory user and I want to check is this user is manager of any Active directory group? Is any command to check user is manager of any ADGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter or ldapfilter to search for the user in the `managedby` attribute. Like

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$username = Read-host "Enter username"
$user = Get-ADUser $username

#If user exists
if($user) {
    #Get groups where user is manager
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(managedby=$($user.DistinguishedName))"

    #If you prefer the more "powershell-like" -Filter, then you can use:
    #Get-ADGroup -Filter "managedby -eq '$($user.DistinguishedName)'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also start from the user object which has all the ManagedBy objects backlinked directly in the managedObjects attribute. Depending on your implementation, this might be much faster:

```
([ADSI]"LDAP://$(Get-ADUser $Username)").ManagedObjects
```